Create a control and set in next to another control
Here is the requirement: set a button aside a textbox. So that the button will be located in the right of the textbox.
At first I think it's easy because I can use UserControl, some drop and drag can do the job. But the problem is, the textbox I use inherits from TextBox (let call in ComplexTextBox), and it has a lot of complex logic, exposes a lot of properties. If I keep using UserControl, then I will have to expose the properties myself, or make the textbox inside UserControl public, which I want to avoid because it looks so stupid.
So I inherit the ComplexTextBox, in the constructor, I do something like this:
public ComplexTextboxWithButtonAside()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    m_btnOpenCharDialog = new KstaButton();
    m_specialCharDialogForm = new ComplexTextboxWithButtonAside(this.components);
    m_specialCharDialogForm.CharacterConfirmedContainer += OnCharacterConfirmedContainer;

    m_btnOpenCharDialog.Parent = this;
    this.Controls.Add(m_btnOpenCharDialog);

    // m_btnOpenCharDialog
    // This is the button I want it to be next to the textbox
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.Image = global::Ksta.Presentation.Properties.Resources.IconLEA;
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.Name = "m_btnOpenCharDialog";
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.ReadOnlyMode = false;
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Size.Width, 0);
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.TabIndex = 0;
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.Text = "";
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.BringToFront();
    this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.Click += OnOpenButtonClick;
}

Seems fine eh?? I create a button and set its Location to the end of the textbox. But when I start the app, the button disappears! When I change that part:
this.m_btnOpenCharDialog.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Size.Width - 50, 0);
then I can see the button. It seems like the textbox has some boundary or something that cover the button.
How can I show the button out of the textbox in this case. I search for 1 day straight but no luck. Please help!
Thank you so much! Please ask me if you find something's wrong.

How about button.Left = textBox.Right;?

You cannot position a Control outside of another. Unless both are child of the same container, as a Form or a UserControl. If the child Button control is outside the bounds of ClientArea of its Parent, you simply cannot see it

I don't know what kind of control you're deriving from, but usually, when you want to create this kind of symbiosis between two otherwise diverse objects, you have to redefine the non-client area of the host and position the child control in that new section, outside of the editable area of the TextBox. Or use a pre-built managed surface, as a UserControl, and do the necessary work to expose all the functionalities you deem necessary in your implementation

Compared to redrawing the non-client area, set public property in UserControl will be easier.
Also you can add a button inside  the textbox.
Check the thread:
Button inside a WinForms textbox
Adjust the position of text
 SendMessage(this.Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(btn.Width << 16));
   


[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

